# How does one visualize elements of standard Iwasawa algebra?

Tags: number-theory, topological-groups, p-adic-number-theory, topological-rings

How does one think of elements of standard Iwasawa algebra of a profinite abelian group $B$ ? I mean like elements of $Z_{p}$ are represented as infinite series, is there a way to think of elements of standard Iwasawa algebra? The definition of Iwasawa algebra itself is horrendous and to think of doing topology on it is overwhelming to me. Thanks!!! ($Z_{p}$ is the ring of *p*-adic integers)

Comment: Different people have different pictures in mind; this is one explanation for some people being able to prove theorems that escaped other (and often better!) mathematicians. But I for one do not think of elements of $\Bbb Z_p$ as infinite series. I think of this ring as a totally disconnected compact group. And go from there.